# how to addapt esp8266 manual to nodemcu

Tags: embedded

I have followed succsefully the manual in the link bellow.
All the VM the hello world program etc..
But My device is NodeMcu not  esp8266 as shown in the photo bellow.
The pinout of Nodemcu is as shown bellow.
I have an FTDI cable with TX RX GND,where do i connect my NODEMCU according to the diagram of the manual shown bellow?
Thanks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hT8EK6bz998&list=PLLYZoEqwvzM1v2hB6Ms0x0UPTWD8DFrUX&index=8

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you saying that you cannot find any pins with RX or TX in the pin name? ... anyway, why don't you use the built in USB connector instead of using the FTDI cable? .... why did you post a video of a device that you do not have?

Comment: No ,of course not.the problem is that nodemcu is much more diverse i has 3 tx rx pairs.the manual is very good but it ment for a more prinitive device unfortunetly i dont know how to addapt it.

Comment: how to adapt it to what? ... why don't you look for NodeMCU tutorials instead of looking at esp8266 tutorials? ... the thing is, the NodeMCU uses the esp8266, so it is unclear what you are having problems with

Comment: because this turial actually shows how to use the sdk in a very ecxelent level.esp8266 is the base of node mcu.

Comment: My suspicion is your nodeMcu board uses a ESP32. That board already has usb->ttl so no need to connect an external one.

Comment: Hello Kartman,You say i can use the MICRO USB cable connection as an alternative?(my NodeMcu is esp8266 based ,not esp32)
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use the Micro USB connector. The NodeMCU has built-in USB to Serial conversion. @Kartman, why would you think the NodeMCU from the question uses an ESP32? The pinout clearly(?) shows an ESP8266.

Comment: The UBuntu software gave me a long output which concluded with this massage shown bellow,i can get these files from the folders,How do configure the MicroUsb connector to act as
the alternative?Thanks,
!!!
No boot needed.
Generate eagle.flash.bin and eagle.irom0text.bin successully in folder bin.
eagle.flash.bin-------->0x00000
eagle.irom0text.bin---->0x10000
!!!

Comment: @rocko446, pinout also shows three uarts - esp32 has three, esp8266 has 1.5. There’s a number of esp32 modules with similar pinout - thus my suspicion. If you had posted an actual picture of your board, that would be more conclusive.